# HTTP Content type of response from server

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have two content types headers on the response URL ? Like can i write a text on the page "downloading started" and download a file (eg :.txt or.xlsx)?

Comment: Nope not possible. You'll want to show have `text/html` then use meta redirect or JavaScript to get the user to download your file. If you implement your own protocol, you could probably get your idea to work, but afaik, http won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, no. I think a HTTP request can only return a single HTTP response.

What you could do is have the normal HTTP response load the HTML page, and have JavaScript in the `OnLoad()` method that executes an AJAX request to another resource to get the file.